# Get column value with same row id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I got this MYSQL table:

```
+---------------+   
|ID|OID|   mpn  |
+--+---+--------+  
|1 | 1 |  12345 |
|2 | 1 |  54321 |
|3 | 2 |  78912 |
|4 | 2 |  12431 |
|5 | 2 |  78787 |
|6 | 3 |  14565 |
.................
```

Now I want to set the values `[mpn]` for each `[OID]` in an array.
Something like this:

```
$oid1 = array([mpn1], [mpn2])
$oid2 = array([mpn1], [mpn2], [mpn3])......
```

Or just manage to output the `[mpn]` referring to `[OID]`. So, I want to get every `MPN` referring to `OID=1`, for example. So, how do I select those values out of the table?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Sure, sorry. So, i want to get every MPN referring to OID=1, for example. So, how do i select those values out of the table?

Comment: `SELECT mpn FROM yourTable WHERE OID=1`?

Comment: `ORDER BY OID` and then construct the arrays.

Comment: Usually we would group by OID, but there is no suitable aggregation function to turn the values into an array, in your case you could easily produce valid JSON with group_concat and just echo in php, if you plan to use the arrays on client side.

Comment: Well, I'm greenhorn. Is it legit solve it like this: "SELECT mpn FROM yourTable ORDER BY OID"
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 if ($row['OID']==3){
 $items_array[] =$row['mpn']; 
}

Comment: @melothias you would also need to select the oid and each time it changes you start to put the mpms in a new array. group_concat and explode works too, but is not safe for varchar.

Comment: Just process the array in a loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here used `COALESCE()` and `GROUP_CONCAT` Functions.

The `GROUP_CONCAT` function concatenates strings from a group into one string with various options.

The `COALESCE` function evaluates the arguments in order and returns the current value of the first expression that initially does not evaluate to NULL.

```
select t.OID,COALESCE( GROUP_CONCAT( t.mpn) , '' ) as mpn
from tableName t 
group by t.OID
```

If mpn have any null value then you can fill up this null value with any String or null. That u want to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `group_concat()`:

```
select oid, group_concat(mpn) as mpns
from t
group by oid;
```

This creates the list of `mon` as a comma-delimited list which you can parse in php.

Comment: Hi Gordon, this is in the Low Quality Posts.  Would you please add a line of explanation to lift it.

Comment: @RohitGupta Just because it's in the low quality post queue doesn't mean it actually *is* a low quality post. That's what that review task is to determine.

Comment: @Mike, which is why I haven't flagged it for deletion.  But to stop others from flagging it, I am suggesting an edit.